# using matrix with cos/sin etc.

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to check if the equation is linear independent so:
$$ \alpha x^2 \cos x + \beta x + \gamma \sin x = 0 $$

I got 3 equations of it:

$$\beta \pi/2 + \gamma = 0$$
$$\alpha \pi^2(-1) + \beta \pi = 0$$
$$\alpha (2\pi^2) + \beta(2\pi) = 0 $$

How can I use a matrix to find $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ ?
what does the matrix need to contain?

Comment: why do you need a matrix? simple elimination should tell you that $\alpha= \beta = \gamma = 0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant you want to find if the following three functions are linearly independent:
$$x^2\cos x, x, \sin x$$

You don't need a matrix to find $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. You can do substitution, or manipulate them algebraically. For example, the last two equations are
$$-\pi\alpha+\beta=0\\
\pi\alpha+\beta=0$$

Adding these two gives you $\beta=0$. You can then find the others by substitution.